# Code first POCO design Entity Identity is not working

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, code-first, poco

I am writing code first Entity Framework app using POCO.
Here is simplified version:

I defined this entity:

```
public class Respondent
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RespondentId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Your Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This entity is used to create a table:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Respondent> Respondents { get; set; }
}
```

I also defined a View Model that contains this entity:

```
public class SurveyModel
{
    public Respondent Respondent { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in code:

```
var survey = new SurveyModel();
survey.Respondent = new Respondent();
```

When I need to write to the DB:

```
private MyContext db = new MyContext();

// HERE, after this line, SHOULD survey.Respondent.RespondentId be +1 ??
// Or only when I call db.SaveChanges() ??
db.Respondents.Add(survey.Respondent);
```

At this moment survey.Respondent.RespondentId must be increased by 1 since it is defined as IDENTITY using the corresponding attribute.

But it doesn't happen.
Please advice what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call db.SaveChanges() in order for it to be saved to the database.

Comment: Yes, I know. But my question is not about how to save data.
I need to know the identity value will be increased only after I call db.SaveChanges() or before, when I add and entity to the entities collection: db.Respondents.Add(survey.Respondent); ???

Comment: It will increase only after you call SaveChanges. Until you call that it's not actually part of the database.

Comment: The identity is generated by the database, not EF.  You have to make the call to the db to get it.